# Are orbits subsets of S

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

In Serge Lang's *Abstact ALgebra*, he define orbits like this:

> let G operate on a set S.  Let $s \in S$. The subset of $S$ consisting of all elements $xs, x\in G$, is called the orbit of $s$ under $G$

How is this a subset of $S$? Can't there be an $x \in G$ such that $xs \not \in S$?

For example, if $S = e$, where $e$ is the identity element, then isn't the orbit of $e$ under $G$,  $G$?

Comment: A group action is a map $G\times S\to S$.

Comment: If $S = \{e\}$, then the orbit of $e$ under $G$ is simply $\{e\}$, and that's because there is only one way of giving a group action on a singleton. See Lord Shark's answer. Be careful of not mixing up $S$ and $G$.

Comment: A group action is a function that takes in a group element, a set element and spits out a set element, **not** a group element.

Answer (score 0):

For each element $s\in S$, the orbit of $s$ is defined by $O_s = \{gs\mid g\in G\}$.
Since $gs\in S$, this is clearly a subset of $S$.

In view of the identity element $e\in G$, by definition $es=s$ for each $s\in S$ and so the orbit of $s$ contains $s$ (choose $g=e$), i.e., $s\in O_s$.

Comment: [quote]For example, if S=e, where e is the identity element, then isn't the orbit of 
e under G, G? [/quote]

Comment: If $S=\{e\}$, then $O_e = \{ge\mid g\in G\} = G$, since $ge=g$.